# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable when calculating loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to implement the training step for a DQN described in [this paper on various RL methods](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.10025.pdf) using TensorFlow, but when I try to compute the gradient using a GradientTape I get a `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:`. Below is the training step code:

```
def train_step(model, target, optimizer, observations, actions, rewards, next_observations):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        target_logits = tf.math.reduce_max(target(np.expand_dims(next_observations, -1)), 1)
        logits = model(np.expand_dims(observations, -1))

        act_logits = np.ndarray(EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE)
        
        for i in range(EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE):
            act_logits[i] = logits[i][actions[i]]

        act_logits = tf.convert_to_tensor(act_logits, dtype=tf.float32)

        y_T = tf.math.add(tf.convert_to_tensor(rewards, dtype=tf.float32), tf.math.scalar_mul(DISCOUNT_RATE, target_logits))

        loss = tf.math.squared_difference(act_logits, y_T)
        loss = tf.math.scalar_mul(1.0 / EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE, loss)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

Where `model` and `target` are tf.keras.Sequential that output the expected value for taking each of 5 possible actions, optimizer is SGD, and `observations`, `actions`, `rewards`, and `next_observations` are numpy arrays sampled from an experience replay buffer.

This is part of implementing the following pseudocode from the aforementioned paper:

[image: DQN Pseudocode]

My best guess is that this error is because indexing `logits` makes the gradient impossible to differentiate, but I don't know else to calculate the Q*(s,a,theta) quantity.

Comment: I found a "solution" by replacing part of my code with this following:

`act_logits = np.zeros((EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE, 5))`
        
        `for i in range(EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE):`
            `act_logits[i][actions[i]] = 1.0`

        `act_logits = tf.math.reduce_max(tf.math.multiply(act_logits, logits), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Solution in the Answer Section for the benefit of the Community.

**`From Comments`**:

The problem is resolved by replacing the code:

```
act_logits = np.ndarray(EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE)
   
for i in range(EXPERIENCE_SAMPLE_SIZE):
    act_logits[i] = logits[i][actions[i]]
```

with the code:

```
act_logits = tf.math.reduce_max(tf.math.multiply(act_logits, logits), 1)
```